# Does exist a built in way to expand a dataset in Weka?

Tags: java, dataset, weka

Do you know of any built in way or method to expand a dataset both in additional instances and additional attributes of these instances, be them existing shared attributes or new ones. So, you are adding additional instances with some existing attrs and some new attrs, like new words in bag-of-words set.

I have searched over the existing methods in weka, and none of them seems to fulfill my demands, they only add instances with same attributes or, instead, they add only new attributes, but no instances at once.